# "Unsigned plaintext JWTs are not supported" java spring

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I'm using `io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts` in my java spring app.
I'm trying to generate a JWT token and decode it immediately (for testing purposes) but it results in an error:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: Unsigned plaintext JWTs are not supported.
```

my code:

```java
        String jws = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getId()).compact();
        String decoded = Jwts.parserBuilder().build().parseClaimsJws(jws).getBody().getSubject();
        System.out.printf("decoded: %s", decoded);
```

If I use .setSigningKey() then the error changes to:
`Signed plaintext JWSs are not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String TOKEN_SECRET = "jwtToken";        
Map<String, Object> claimMaps = new HashMap<>();
claimMaps.put("id", "123123123");
String jws = Jwts.builder().signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, TOKEN_SECRET).setClaims(claimMaps).setSubject("wahaha").compact();
System.out.println(jws);
Claims decoded = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(TOKEN_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(jws).getBody();
System.out.printf("decoded: %s", decoded);
```

console output

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ3YWhhaGEiLCJpZCI6IjEyMzEyMzEyMyJ9.VtYAMdh1J9HxnLD3P6jKmY2018K_f0HUqsXxcy39em8LCTbZpwtAoj46lHcPFyfCWPi8knsIw1zWdayyjVeLcA
```

decoded: {sub=wahaha, id=123123123}

Comment: That doesn't work: `The signing key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS512 algorithm.` How can I make it accept such short token secrets?

Comment: I don't know how to make it accept a shorter SECRET key.
You can make the secret key longer. The longer the secret key will have no effect on your code